# Nested startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity A` that calls an `Activity B` using `startActivityForResult()`. Under certain conditions `Activity B` needs to call on `Activity C` for another result so I use the `startActivityForResult()` method again.

However, when I `setResult()` and `finish()` in `Activity C`, it calls the `onActivityResult()` method in `Activity A` instead of `Activity B`.

Is there a way to get around this ??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. The activity you call is implied in the Intent. So how can you use the same startActivityForResult() for starting two different Activities?

Comment: By same, I meant the method... so I use the `startActivityForResult()` method instead of the `startActivity()` method

Comment: If B is calling C do you not have a separate intent and callback method?

Comment: You want to pass result from Activity C to Activity A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not sure i understood.

you mean that this is the scenario you wish to be :

A -> B -> C ; B <- C , A <- B

yet the current scenario is :

A -> B -> C ; A <- C

where -> denotes a 'calls activity' and <- denotes a 'gets result from'.

maybe you just called "finish()" on activity B , or maybe you've set "noHistory=true" for it?

Comment: I've edited your answer to make the situation more clear and it was actually the "noHistory = true" that was causing problem. Cheers.

Comment: ok , though now i don't understand what i've written . the "->" was for activity transition (activities stack)   ,while "=>" meant what occured after closing the last activity .